# Implementing a wx.Styled Text Control in wxPython for Application

Tags: python, wxpython, scintilla

I am creating a very basic IDE for wxpython and python, and at the moment I have a big `wx.textctrl`.I am typing my code into, I heard it wasn't a good practice and I'm better off using the `wx.Stc.StyledTextControl` from the scintilla library.

How would I implement this styled text control with a size and syntax highlighting?? Can someone please lead me in the right direction, the documentation is very poor.

Thankyou.

The code thus far: http://pastebin.com/VvxspyjX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scintilla component is the only rational choice for an editor, but yes, it lacks a proper documentation. The best source/reference is certainly [this page](http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/index.html).

The [API documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_styled_text_ctrl.html) and the [wiki](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxStyledTextCtrl) are useful sources too. The wxPython docs and demos also contain exemples using the control.

Finally, note that wxStyledTextCtrl is a (thin) wrapper around the (fat) [Scintilla API](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html), so the latter can be used as a reference too.

Comment: The first link is now deprecated

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150227190255/http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/index.html